# Decode json string using Base64 in php with json_decode

Tags: php, json, base64

I'm trying to decode output json data using json_decode & Base64 decode, no issue for output  json_decode but one string that have base64 encode I also no issue to decode it using base64_decode,. but I'm try to decode both json data using json_decode & base64_decode that i face some problems,  My question is now how to decode the JSON string on same time one string use base64 decode... here an example of my json data

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [ad_id] => 257
        [stat] => 1
        [text] => 2YTZhNio2YrYuSDYtNmB2LEg2YPYp9io2KrZitmB2YrYpyDZhdmI2K/ZitmEINmi2aDZoNmp
        [img_count] => 4
        [img_file_name] => 8246ee83.jpg
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [ad_id] => 258
        [stat] => 1
        [text] => 2YTZhNio2YrYuSDYtNmB2LEg2KfZhCDYqtmKINiy2K8g2YXZiNiv2YrZhCDZotmg2aDZpQ==
        [img_count] => 5
        [img_file_name] => 1563457.jpg
    )
```

string 'text' as output working ..but with limit array [0] << one output only if i replace $output[0] with $output[1] i got output of array 1 like that ,,i need to be dynamic [0] or [1] or [2] ..etc base on output.. ,,and print the other strings with json_decode.

```
<?
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/s=0&c=20");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0;  SM-N9005 Build/LRX21V)' );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode( $result, TRUE);
$output[0]['text']=base64_decode($json[0]['text']);
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

#print_r ($json);

print_r ($output);

?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, do this:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($json as $k => $v){ // this will loop through all the possible indexes
    $output[$k]['text'] = base64_decode($v['text']);
}
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
print_r($output); // here's your new PHP array with all the ['text'] values!
```

Comment: superb.. Got it.. Thanks a lot... it's work but only printout the **text** string but not all other strings.  need little editing.